# How to run script b based on script a result

Tags: bash, shell

I've got two working scripts: a.sh, b.sh.

I would like to create one script which will do the following:
1. Run a.sh
2. Running b.sh is dependant on the output of a.sh so wait for a String from a.sh standatd output saying 'a.sh launched' only then run b.sh If this is too trickyto to implement then perhaps simply wait for say 2 minutes before running the second script.

What would be the best way acheiving this?

Comment: Does script `b.sh` should run only if `a.sh` completed successfully?

Comment: So both scripts runs simultaneously?

Comment: Script b.sh should run only if a.sh completed successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuously reads output of `a.sh` and when it encounters *"a.sh launched"* it launches `b.sh`.

```
./a.sh | while read line; do
    echo $line      # if you want to see the output of a.sh
    [ "$line" == "a.sh launched" ] && ./b.sh &
done
```

If you want to match

```
a.sh lounched at `date`
```

use advanced bash comparsion

```
[[ "$line" =~ "a.sh lounched".* ]]
```

Comment: Thank you. When I run this I don't see the output of a.sh, is it also possible to make sure I see it in the standard output so that I could keep track of what's going on? Also, is it possible for $line to contain a String and not exact equel as it also contains a timestamp which obviously changes? Will =~ do the trick?